# Problem with numerator on a fraction

Tags: fractions

When i write the following line of code: $\frac{$\alpha_{n}$}{2}$ = $\frac{\pi}{n}$ , It displays me this:
[image]

What can I do do have the numerator above the line ? when I remove the "n" index it displays it correcly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post the code you used (in a small, yet complete, code).

Comment: Note you would have an error message from the code you showed. If you want help with an error show the error message (from the log file) the PDF output after an error is not intended to be usable.

Comment: You are switching to and from math mode too much (and ignoring errors, which is no good). As you can see in the answer, you enter math mode with `$` or `\(` and exit it at the end of the *whole* formula...

Answer (score 1):

You should write: `$\frac{\alpha_{n}}{2} = \frac{\pi}{n}$`

Comment: No, I was wrong, sorry